# Display custom text if asp.net mvc for each loop is empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreach

Still learning asp.net and mvc, please be gentle :)

Currently setting up an MVC view to consume and display an RSS feed, using [this method described on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39114/Consuming-RSS-Feed-in-MVC-ASP-NET.aspx).

What I want to do is when no items are returned for the RSS feed, display a custom piece of text, eg something like the following piece of psuedocode.

```
If ViewData.Model.Items is not empty
 Then run the for loop
 Else display "sorry, no items to display"
End If
```

I know how to do this from my classic ASP days if I was displaying records from a table, being:

```
If tablename.EOF And tablename.BOF Then...
```

But I don't have the first clue as to how this is acheived in .net, particually when the results are rendered using a for loop.

If you can point me in the right direction of where I should be looking it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually do something stupidly simple like this

```
<%
if(Model.Items.Count >0){
   foreach(..)
}
else{
%>
    Sorry, no items to display
<%
}
%>
```

I guess the proper way would also be to put this in a html helper extension, but above works for me

Comment: If it works, I won't knock it, and it makes perfect sense - thanks muchly.